# Bash - Get response from Netcat as hex

Tags: bash, terminal, hex, echo, netcat

I’m currently working with a kvm switch that takes hex commands over tcp and returns a response. When on my Mac, I can run:

echo -e -n ‘\xAA\xBB\x01\x00’ >
| netcat 192.169.2.43 4500

And when it’s finished, it will wait and then print out a response continuously that can be converted and read back as the proper hex response. However, when I do this on my Raspberry Pi, the same command finishes without any output. Is there something I can do on Linux to get it to output the response? (ideally just a single response rather than continuously)

I’ve tried looking into the various modifiers for netcat, and tried the -q modifier with a number value to see if that would help, but it waits without outputting any values.

Comment: Are you sure that `echo` command is printing what you want it to? `echo` with options is hopelessly inconsistent between different platforms, shells, and even different modes in the same shell. `printf` is much better, though a bit harder to use (see [this Unix&Linux question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo)). Also, do you have the correct single-quotes? The ones in the question are "fancy" unicode quotes that won't work as shell syntax, and may be causing trouble. Try piping to `xxd` instead of `netcat` to see what's actually being sent.

Comment: @GordonDavisson : While the `echo` versions differ - in particular between Mac and Linux -, the OP tagged the question as _bash_, which means that the **internal** command _echo_ is used. I don't know whether the bash _echo_  differs between different bash versions, but aside from this problem, the code should be portable.

Comment: Add to your question the bash versions you use on the two platforms (i.e. `echo $BASH_VERSION`); and, for the safe side, do also a `type echo` - see my previous comment to Gordon Davisson for this.

Comment: @user1934428 After running it, it looks like the Mac is running 3.2.57(1)-release and the pi is running 4.4.12(1)-release. Also, when I run type echo it says "echo is a shell builtin". I did also check using xxd and it looks like the output is exactly the same from both echo commands, and I'm not using unicode quotes in the command within my terminal as well.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Wouldn't let me tag two people but the above comment should have responses. Also I keep getting "read(net): Connection reset by peer" after a while and have to reset my switch, but that might be unrelated.

Comment: Also I'm sorry, the pi is actually running 5.1.4(1)-release. I was looking at the wrong pi.

Comment: I don't know what they put into bash 5, but I think your echo is supposed to be compatible. If xxd shows the same output in both cases, the problem is not related to bash itself, but perhaps to differences in `netcat` on both platforms.  May I suggest that you repost this question at [su] or [se]?